# stopping LaunchAgent when uninstalling package

Tags: macos, launchd, launch-agent

I build an app which provides LaunchAgent (an small UI app with "tray" icon; let's say that defined in `/Library/LaunchAgents/foo.plist`.

When installing package launchctl loads this LaunchAgent description automatically and starts processes for all logged-in users. (i.e i don't have to load it using launchctl load like i have to do with LaunchDaemons).

When i uninstall package, all files - including LaunchAgent plist file in `/Library/LaunchAgents` are removed but processes are still running.

(i have several users logged in, so there are several instances of this agent)

Now, how should i tell root launchd to stop these processes (for unspecified number of users) when running as root ? (note, launchctl ran as root doesn't even see those agents).

(pid-files,`killall more-or-less-unique-executable-name` is last resort and i'm keeping these solution as last resort)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
LOGGEDUSERS=`who | grep console | awk '{ print $1 }'`
for CURRUSER in $LOGGEDUSERS
do
    su -l $CURRUSER -c 'launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/your.plist'
done
```

In my uninstaller script there is also `killall -15 <app_name>` after that code (just in case)

Comment: Thanks. For me it counts like "hack" solution, but let's accept reality and forget about that ...

Comment: BTW, grep is redundant here ... one pipe is enough:

LOGGEDUSERS=`who | awk '/console/ { print $1 }'`