# OS X: How do you create an installer .pkg that sets up one launchd plist as root and one as the current user?

Tags: macos, package, launchd

I need to create a package installer on OS X that handles the installation of two launched daemons: one that runs as root and one that runs as the current user.  While this is just for a very small internal deployment, I can make no guarantees as to what the current username is.  How can I either:

- Make sure that the latter has the proper username set in the launchd plist file?

OR

- Ensure that each one is setup by the proper invocation of launchctl, one that's using "sudo" and one that's not?

Answer (score 3):

In your postflight script just do something like this:

```
launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.my.daemon.plist

LOGGEDUSERS=`who | awk '/console/ { print $1 }'`
for CURRUSER in $LOGGEDUSERS
do
    su -l $CURRUSER -c 'launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.agent.plist'
done
```

Take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638873/stopping-launchagent-when-uninstalling-package) for some additional info